# How to cancel edit on Kendo Grid?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

In my kendo grid, I have a situation where, when they click on a cell, it will be in edit mode. But depending on a condition, I need to cancel the edit.

I tried using the code to simulate the escape key press in jQuery but that didnt work.

Comment: Maybe this will help you 


[Kendo Grid cancel edit event][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499478/kendo-grid-cancel-edit-event

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use

```
 $('#grid').data("kendoGrid").closeCell();
```

on your event or you can put this in your edit event itself like:-

```
if($(e.container).index()==1)
         $('#list').data("kendoGrid").closeCell();
```

for reference you can see this JSfiddle example here i am using this code for second column,if you will click on second column of the grid then it will close the cell.

JSfiddle link:-http://jsfiddle.net/Eh8GL/250/