# Create button click event using class in jquery in Kendo Editor Tool

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, kendo-editor

I am using Kendo Editor Tool in my MVC application and In 'Insert File' button I have renamed the Cancel button to Close. Once I upload the files and click on close button, the previous page which contains grid should refresh.

I have created a button click like this -

```
 $('.k-dialog-close.k-button').click(function () {
       alert('clicked');
    });
```

The above code is not working and hence I am unable to call this button click function. Please help me regarding same.

For Reference I am attaching the screenshot.

[Please click here to view the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lns8U.png)

As per the screenshot, The Kendo Editor Tool is customized and once Files are uploaded and Close button is pressed the grid behind should refresh.

Below is the html structure, hope this helps -

```
<div class="k-edit-buttons k-state-default">
<button class="k-dialog-insert k-button k-primary">Insert</button>
<button class="k-dialog-close k-button">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Kendo Grid cancel edit event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14499478/kendo-grid-cancel-edit-event)

Comment: Thanks but it didn't. I have attached a screenshot for reference, if it may help you to understand the question.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing `">"` in selector between two classes 
try below script and you are ready to go.

```
 $('.k-dialog-close >.k-button').click(function () {
       alert('clicked');
    });
```

Comment: Not working. In Kendo Editor tool there's a 'Insert File' button and in that popup there are two buttons - Insert and Cancel, So I want to call/create a button click event for Cancel button.

Comment: Can you give html structure copied from inspector window

Comment: I have added html structure, hope this helps

Comment: this should give you click event on close button $(document).on('click','.k-dialog-close',function(){   alert('clicked');  })